# Cannot resolve symbol method error

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi guys can someone help me out there. I installed Android Studio version145.3537739 on windows platform but when i open the new project, it gives errors like 'method does not override method in upper class and cannot resolve symbol errors. Can someone help me pliz. I have tried to go to file and invalidate cache and restart but i cant get it solved

Comment: Either your project haven't build successfully or android SDK will not installed properly.

Comment: Mmmmm i tried to build and rebuild the project and reinstalled the android SDK